# VBA More effective way of data trimming

Tags: vba, excel

My code consists of `Split`, `Mid`, `Left`, `Right` and `Replace` functions which are used to trim my data into a more neat manner. However, it's too long and inefficient, it takes too much time to go through all this because I have up to thousands of files that will go through this.

My main code goes through a folder and goes through all the files inside the folder to find and search for strings and then copy it out into a new worksheet.

```
'Test RowA(1)
wks.Cells(BlankRow, 1).Replace What:="testtest         : ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

---

```
'Start RowB(2)
wks.Cells(BlankRow, 2).Replace What:="  Started at: ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

---

```
'Temp RowC(3)
Dim strSearchC As String
Dim cCell As Range
Dim s3 As String
strSearchC = "testflyy"

Set cCell = wks.Cells(BlankRow, 3).Find(What:=strSearchC, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not cCell Is Nothing Then
s3 = Split(cCell.Value, ":")(1)
s3 = Mid(s3, 1, 3)
cCell.Value = s3
End If
```

---

```
'Type RowD(4)
Dim strSearchD As String
Dim dCell As Range
Dim s4 As String
strSearchD = "testflyy"

Set dCell = wks.Cells(BlankRow, 4).Find(What:=strSearchD, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not dCell Is Nothing Then
s4 = Split(dCell.Value, "_", 3)(2)
s4 = Mid(s4, 1, 3)
dCell.Value = s4
End If
```

---

```
'No RowF(6)
Dim strSearchF As String
Dim fCell As Range
Dim s6 As String
strSearchF = "homebeestrash_archivetestts"

Set fCell = wks.Cells(BlankRow, 6).Find(What:=strSearchF, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
s6 = Split(fCell.Value, "testts")(1)
s6 = Mid(s6, 1, 2)
fCell.Value = s6
End If
```

---

```
'End RowG(7)
Dim strSearchG As String
Dim gCell As Range
Dim s7 As String
strSearchG = "homebeestrash_archivetestts"

Set gCell = wks.Cells(BlankRow, 7).Find(What:=strSearchG, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not gCell Is Nothing Then
s7 = Split(gCell.Value, "reports")(1)
s7 = Split(s7, "Report")(0) 
s7 = Left(s7, 8) & " " & Right(s7, 6)
```

---

```
'Month RowH(8)
wks.Cells(BlankRow, 8).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Left(s7, 4) & "-" & Mid(s7, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(s7, 7, 2)) '<~~ get 2019-03-02
gCell.Value = s7
End If
```

Basically these are to trim the already extracted data in each respective rows worksheet, Row A and B is just simply replacing the data with nothing, for Row C onwards to Row H,, i will search if the string exists on the particular row and then use `Split` or `Right`, `Left`, `Mid` functions.

Question: Is there any other way to write it more efficiently because there are too many codings with formats like this and I feel like its slowing my program down a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you please clarify what the code is supposed to do? It looks more like a proof-of-concep than like something that actually accomplishes something, but a proper description might just fix that.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, please have a look.

Comment: Much better, can you also provide a better title? The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: What kind of files are being searched?  There are much better ways to process the files but no way to advise on it without mock data.

Comment: The coding that i have provided  above is just trimming of the data that has already been copied into the worksheet, basically i find whether or not the string exists in the worksheet, if yes then trim it down using split, Right,Left,Mid functions, sometimes replace.

Answer (score 2):

So I had a look at your code and I got confused to what you were trying to do with find. So I had to test it out for myself. If I understand it correctly you are using it to figure out if a string contains the value you are looking for. If it does you continue processing if not you skip it.

However, this can be done by fetching the cell value and performing `InStr <> 0` to do the same thing.

I wrote a quick VBA to see the performance of find in relation to InStr. The results of this was (as you can test yourself now) that the `.Find` method took aproximately 5 seconds to compute, whereas the `InStr` one finishes instantly. When running on 100000 lines it takes almost a minute to complete, whereas the `InStr` one finishes instantly. So since you perform the `Cells(x,y).Find` for 4 separate columns in thousand of files I would say that this is your main culprit for timeloss.

```
Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = TimeValue(Now)

For i = 0 To 10000
Dim x
Set x = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Find(What:="12", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1.Cells(1, 4) = "Yup"
    End If
Next i
Sheet1.Cells(1, 3).Value = TimeValue(Now)
Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = TimeValue(Now)
For i = 0 To 10000
Set x = Sheet1.Cells(2, 1)
    If InStr(x, "12") <> 0 Then
        Sheet1.Cells(2, 4) = "Yup"
    End If
Next i
Sheet1.Cells(2, 3).Value = TimeValue(Now)
```

On top of that you are running `Cells(x,y).Replace` which is about twice as slow as just setting the value of the Replace as seen below.

```
wks.Cells(BlankRow, 1) = Replace(wks.Cells(BlankRow, 1),"string to remove","")
```

The methods you are running for Find and Replace are supposed to be executed on Ranges for the maximum efficiency. Say if you instead running replace on each cell one by one you execute it on the entire column straight away like this:

```
wks.Columns(1).Replace What:="testtest         : ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Then you will notice that the Replace is performed in less than a second for all rows. Making it a lot faster if you have massive files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying it out yourself! i'm trying it out now and sorry for asking this, could you please explain to me your coding? like how it works? because i'm still very new to vba i'm not able to understand complicated codings

Comment: Sure, Top code does the same thing in two different ways. It's a benchmark where I perform the task the way you do it in the first loop 10000 times. Before I do that I print the time it started into a cell (Unnecessary for your code) and after it I print the end time into another cell. So Now I have Start and End time of the execution.

Comment: For the second loop I perform the task in another way where I just fetch the value of the cell and use string methods instead to perform the search for "12" in your case this would be "testflyy". If the result of InStr is 0 then no match was found. So If InStr(x,"12") <> 0 means that as long as the result is not 0 the string "12" was found. This gives the same result as your Find method since it searches for a string and if it is not found it is not processed.

Comment: The second set where we target the Replace method we would want to execute the Replace on all rows before we start processing them. So before you start iterating on BlankRow you would Call the new replace method from my code block so that all fields are properly formatted from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! for the first part of the coding, do you search for "12" and then write in "Yup" if it exists? what if i want to write in whatever comes after 12? basically the whole string?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes exactly. As long as you get a match it will be Not 0. So if you search for 1234 on a string with value 1234 InStr will returen 1 for the start position of 1234. If you search for 12345 on string 1234 you get no match and it returns 0.